# Next js middleware не работает fetch

Tags: javascript, laravel, nextjs, next.js

Не работает запрос на сервер в middleware.ts, однако такой же запрос пробовал делать на странице и он отрабатывает как должен. Попробовал взять фейковый апи и вывести в middleware, он тоже отработал как надо. В чем может быть проблема? бэк написан на laravel

вот код:

```
    await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log('json', json))
        .then(data => data).catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
```

Comment: `.then(json => console.log('json', json))` — и тут ты благополучно потерял все данные

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена, запрос сделал таким:

```
headers: new Headers({
            'authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
```